# Does assigning a function to a variable in javascript run the function

Tags: javascript, var

I have three simple programs below with different outputs. I am a bit confused as to why I get a different output. What really happens when you assign a function to a variable? Does it not run unless you have parentheses (i.e. `myfunction()`)? I'm also very confused as to how JavaScript allows the parenthesis behind a function as 'optional' when calling it. Can someone clear this up? I only know Java so this is all new territory for me.

```
// ------First--------------------------------
var x = 9;
function myfunction (){
  x = 3;
}
var w = myfunction;
w();
console.log(x);
//output is 3


// ---------Second -----------------------------
var x = 9;
function myfunction (){
  x = 3;
}
var w = myfunction;
console.log(x);
//output is 9


// ---------Third -----------------------------
var x = 9;
function myfunction (){
  x = 3;
}
var w = myfunction();
console.log(x);
//output is 3
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it does not. A reference to a function by name is simply a reference to a value, like any other value.  Without the `()` operator, it's not a function call.

Parentheses are *not* optional when calling a function *except* when it's being called via the `new` operator. Thus:

```
function foo() {
  console.log("hi!");
}

var otherFoo = foo; // no function call
var obj = new foo;  // function call via "new"
var x = foo();      // function call via "()"
```

Comment: Thanks Pointy. Can you please give an example of the "new operator" and how the call would happen...